# UIView doesn't size itself to superView

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `UIView` with constraints like this:

[image]

All vertical and horizontal spaces are set to 0.

Then in `viewDidLoad` I added a `view` as the `subview` of the original `UIView`. Here is what it looks like:

```
self.innerView  = [[UIView all] initWithFrame:self.myView.frame];
[self.myView addSubview:self.innerView];
```

When I run the app, `innerView` doesn't size itself to `myView`. What can I do to fix that?

Comment: Since you're adding the first UIView you talk about in the storyboard, why not add innerView there as well, and add the constraints it should have there?

Comment: I added a custom view. (I didn't say that in the question because I wanted to keep it simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding your view with code, you need to add constraints to your `innerview` with code as well. See [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutinCode/AutoLayoutinCode.html) on how to do that. Basically you need the innerview view to have leading and trailing spaces to the parent `myView` (both horizontally and vertically).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! The `UIView` is really a custom class in which I assigned in the storyboard. If I set the constraints in the custom class, when I add the constraints, should I add them to self?

Comment: not sure what you mean by adding them to self. Even if it is a custom class, you can add the constraints just like any other view in storyboard

Answer (score 0):

The constraints should be added to the container view, in this case, it is self.myView. I did not see your code to add constraints to self.myView.